# Polymorphic NHibernate mappings

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, interface

I have an interface `IUserLocation` and a concrete type `UserLocation`.

When I use ICriteria, specifying the *interface* `IUserLocation`, I want NHibernate to instantiate a collection of the *concrete* `UserLocation` type.

I have created an HBM mapping file using the [table per concrete type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) strategy (shown below). However, when I query NHibernate using ICriteria I get:

> **NHibernate cannot instantiate abstract class or interface MyNamespace.IUserLocation**

Can anyone see why this is? (source code for the relevant bit of NHibernate [here](http://github.com/leemhenson/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Tuple/PocoInstantiator.cs) (I think))

My ICriteria:

```
var filter = DetachedCriteria.For<IUserLocation>()
                             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserId", userId));

return filter.GetExecutableCriteria(UoW.Session)
             .List<IUserLocation>();
```

My mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="MyNamespace.IUserLocation,MyAssembly" abstract="true" table="IUserLocations">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="UserId" column="UserId" type="System.Guid"></key-property>
      <key-many-to-one name="Location" column="LocationId" class="MyNamespace.ILocation,MyAssembly"></key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>
    <union-subclass table="UserLocations" name="MyNamespace2.UserLocation,MyAssembly2">
      <property name="IsAdmin" />
    </union-subclass>    
  </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation it looks like your mapping file should do it to me.  I've never tried table per concrete class though.  And I notice the examples in the [NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) for it don't use interfaces for the base class.  Perhaps it's not supported?

I have used [Table per concrete class, using implicit polymorphism](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcreate-polymorphism) before with a separate mapping for each subclass.

```
<class name="MyNamespace.UserLocation,MyAssembly" table="UserLocations">
    ...
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks David. It occurs to me that I may be barking up the wrong tree, as I am trying to use NHibernate a bit like an IOC container here, instantiating a concrete type where I only supply an interface. If NHibernate supports this, I think it'd be pretty useful.

Due to limitations of the solution I am working with it is impractical to modify the interface to be an abstract base class. As a temporary hack I am using the IOC container to resolve the concrete type of the interface for supply to the ICriteria.

Comment: I started looking at this again and I noticed that if the mapping file uses UserLocation instead of IUserLocation and the union-subclass is removed you can still reference it as IUserLocation in the criteria and get back an IList<IUserLocation>.